# System message to encourage meta discussion

Tags: discussion

OK, so I put up a system message to encourage people to come here and help decide on the essential meta discussions:

> Help decide the [7 essential meta questions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta-essentials) for this site while it’s in beta on [meta.english](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/). We need your input!

I did this somewhat unilaterally because I wanted to kick start more discussion on meta regarding important but boring matters like the domain name and the FAQ and what is on-topic and what is not.

Please chime in on this question with your opinions of this message. Do you have a better wording? It’s currently set to expire on Saturday, but it can be deleted and replaced at any time. days Let us (the moderators) know what you think and we can fine-tune the messaging.

Comment: Way to go! I always envied all the other beta sites that feature such messages. (Some even update them quite often to keep users interested, directing their attention to new issues as they come up.)

Comment: I hate to say it... but I didn't even notice. Perhaps we've had a system message for too long already.